# query versions of same record to find differences

Tags: sql, ms-access, pivot

So I have this access db table which basically stores approximately the same set of data every week. However, there might be minor differences, that I need to point out. How would I query this? In excel I'd make a pivot table, and check the values, but surely there must be a less time consuming way using a dynamic query?

Example table:

```
[Version_Date] |   [ItemNumber]    |  [Weight]
Nov 11 2013    |         1         |     3
Oct 29 2013    |         1         |     3
Nov 11 2013    |         2         |     4
Oct 29 2013    |         2         |     3
Nov 11 2013    |         3         |     2
Oct 29 2013    |         3         |     5
```

query should return a list like this

```
[ItemNumber]  | [Oct 29 2013]  |   [Nov 11 2013  |   [Delta]
1             |          3     |        3        |       0
2             |          3     |        4        |       1
3             |          5     |        3        |      -2
```

Thanks in advance for any help/hints.

Comment: Is your [Version_Date] column a true `Date/Time` column?

Comment: Access supports cross tab queries which are similar to the pivot you'd use in excel.  However, is your delta always based on two different version_dates? or could there be more than 2?

Comment: @GordThompson - Yes, it is.. but for the purpose of example, I simplified it

Comment: @xQbert there will be two versions, as I will compare the latest two. Good remark though thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For sample data in [ExampleTable]

```
Version_Date  ItemNumber  Weight
------------  ----------  ------
2013-11-11             1       3
2013-10-29             1       3
2013-11-11             2       4
2013-10-29             2       3
2013-11-11             3       2
2013-10-29             3       5
```

the query

```sql
SELECT 
    t1.ItemNumber, 
    t2.Version_Date AS Previous_Date, 
    t2.Weight AS Previous_Weight, 
    t1.Version_Date, 
    t1.Weight, 
    t1.Weight - t2.Weight AS Delta
FROM
    ExampleTable t1
    INNER JOIN
    ExampleTable t2
        ON t2.ItemNumber = t1.ItemNumber
            AND t2.Version_Date < t1.Version_Date
```

returns

```
ItemNumber  Previous_Date  Previous_Weight  Version_Date  Weight  Delta
----------  -------------  ---------------  ------------  ------  -----
         1  2013-10-29                   3  2013-11-11         3      0
         2  2013-10-29                   3  2013-11-11         4      1
         3  2013-10-29                   5  2013-11-11         2     -3
```

so that gives you the numbers, you just need to put them into a report to make them look pretty.